# Creating polygon from perpendicular projection of light on wall on DEM using GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

**Scenario:**

I have

1. a DEM
2. a Polyline with elevation, representing a man made barrier like a levee or a giant wall.

Polyline will always be on top of DEM.

I want to get a polygon that represent all the areas that will be shaded if we were to project a perpendicular light along the wall.

Do we have tools in GRASS to achieve this?

**Sketch:**

I want the blue polygon.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a classic "visibility" problem, albeit with a quirky 3D observer. You'll need to mask in the wall to the DEM.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have played with grass r.sunmask but have realized it is not what I need because the sun in my case is all along the wall not at just one point.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Vince pointed out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390405/create-a-polygon-from-perpendicular-projection-of-light-on-a-wall-on-dem#comment639395_390405), the GRASS module `r.viewshed`  ([man page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.viewshed.html)) will achieve what you want. You'll need to first "burn" the wall into your DEM. Then set the `coordinates=` parameter to the location of the light, and use the `-b` parameter so that the output raster will have 1 or 0 for visible/invisible (i.e. lighted/dark).

Comment: If I set the light location as coordinates it will be just one point. My light source is an XYZ line.

Comment: There is also the addon r.viewshed.cva - Undertakes a "cumulative viewshed analysis" using a vector points map as input "viewing" locations, using r.viewshed to calculate the individual viewsheds (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.viewshed.cva.html)